# Storage On Ubuntu dedicated server 18:04

Tags: storage

My dedicated server Spec's

```
Unmetered Bandwidth | Gigabit Conn.
Any Linux/Windows* OS available!
Intel Core i7-2600 - Quad Core (8t)
16GB RAM | 2x 3TB HDD Space
Located in Europe & USA!
Custom ISO through IPMI request!
```

What I have done is to install GUI on the server. When I use vnc to see the desktop, the storage available is 1 TB, but when I go to storage in settings, it shows the 2x 3 TB HDD. My question is how do I access them?

I have tried formatting them to mount them.  It only worked on one of the 3 TB HDD drive but didn't work on the other one. It crashed the server as I assume OS was installed on part of 3 TB.

Thank you